# Dummy Output on Intel Jasper Lake N5100

Tags: sound, audio

No sound, no speakers and no microphone in sound settings. I see Dummy Output in the pavucontrol. I tried the options `snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1` in alsa-base.conf and BOOT_CMD in GRUB, it didn't help.

I use /usr/share/alsa-base/alsa-info.sh script for get more diagnoctic information. [Result](https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=bdc7d9a6cbf5db1d5727600671256196edf8dc7f)

```
System:    Host: slayki1405 Kernel: 5.11.0-41-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Pantheon 
           Distro: elementary OS 6 Odin 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ALLDOCUBE product: i1405 v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: ALLDOCUBE model: ALLDOCUBE serial: <superuser/root required> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: Z362D.ES8336.2103034.06 date: 05/20/2021 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-41-generic
```

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 4dc8 (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 1242
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 133
    Memory at 6001120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6001000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

```
aplay -l
**** Список PLAYBACK устройств ****
карта 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
карта 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
карта 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
карта 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
карта 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
карта 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
карта 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep -C1 -E 'ALSA|HDA|snd|DSP|audio'
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.11.0-41-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-005) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1-generic 5.11.22)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic root=/dev/mapper/data-root ro quiet splash snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
--
[    0.050392] Policy zone: Normal
[    0.050394] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic root=/dev/mapper/data-root ro quiet splash snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.052209] Dentry cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes, linear)
--
[    3.332452] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[    3.376815] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.377242] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    3.403394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: f8:5e:a0:2d:c0:3f
[    3.412669] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[    3.412722] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[    3.412767] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[    3.412810] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[    3.412868] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[    3.412915] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[    3.412955] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
[    3.415753] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with JasperLake on Manjaro.
Look here:

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/jasper-lake-hd-audio-recognized-but-no-sound-as-usual/117082/9

I used:

sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/dspcfg.conf <<< 'options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1'

which is suggested in the site and now the audio works!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you will need to check:

1. Are the dependencies correct?

   ```
   modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
   ```

   So long as everything is installed, you should see something like this:

   ```
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
   install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
   install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/ac97_bus.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/soc/snd-soc-core.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-bus.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-cadence.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-generic-allocation.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-intel.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
   insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
   ```

   If you see just a few `.ko` references, then you may need to determine which drivers are required for your audio device and `apt install` them individually.
2. Does the kernel module exist?

   ```
   find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/sound -name snd-hda-intel.ko
   ```

   If it does, you'll see something like this:

   ```
   /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
   ```

   If the kernel is missing, you may be able to install it like this:

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
   ```

Hopefully this will give you what you need for the sound to be restored

Comment: I got a similar result for the command modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel, everything needed is installed. The kernel module snd-hda-intel.ko is also present.
Any ideas? ️

Comment: I use /usr/share/alsa-base/alsa-info.sh script for get more information. Result: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=bdc7d9a6cbf5db1d5727600671256196edf8dc7f

Answer (score 0):

The support for the Everest ES8336 sound card is discussed in this thread within thesofproject:
https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/3248